# Skip first letters of all values returned from a sql server database

Tags: sql

I don't want to return the first three letters in the return values.
An example:

```sql
select companyname from companies 
-- returns companyX
```

Can I write a query that returns panyX instead?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`select right(companyname, len(companyname)-3) as companyname` will do the thing (this should work for microsoft T-SQ, see more string functions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx) )

Comment: Sorry to necro, but this only skips the first 2 characters and Peter's request asked for skipping 3.

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't say what RDBMS you're using, here is an ANSI-compliant answer:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(mycolumn,3,CHARACTER_LENGTH(mycolumn))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(companyname, 3, len(companyname) - 2)
  FROM companies
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bunch of string manipulation stuff for sql

[Tutorial 4: SQL functions](http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/oracle-9i/sql-functions/1.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTR(COMPANYNAME,3) 
FROM COMPANIES;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can solve your issue by using following queries,

```
 --> select substring([image],4,len([image])) from dbo.emp
```

and

```
 --> select replace([image],'ima','') from dbo.emp
```

Thanks

Venkat